# 'Last Friday, we have announced 18 trainees who [HAVE BEEN/ WERE] selected to join our program'

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense, present-perfect

1. Last Friday, we have announced 18 trainees who **were** selected to join our program.
2. Last Friday, we have announced 18 trainees who **have been** selected to join our program.

which one is correct?

Comment: You've already gone wrong by your ***third*** word! It should start *Last Friday, **we announced** 18 trainees...* - Present Perfect ***have announced*** doesn't normally work when attached to a specific time in the past, since the whole *point* of the usage is to identify actions that *continue up until the present*. You ***can*** use Present Perfect for the subordinate clause, but you don't ***have*** to. And that error at the start of the example should be all the proof you need that ***you're overusing Perfect verb forms*** - so if only for that reason, I suggest you avoid it completely.

Comment: Thank you! It really helps me

Comment: Because TEFL teachers think they *understand* Perfect verb forms, they probably devote too much time to showing how they ***can*** be used. But in practice, many/most learners would probably gain greater fluency in English if they concentrated on learning how they can ***avoid*** Perfect forms! :)

Comment: The PP just tells us a thing is in the past, not when. The SP implies an event occurred specifically at a time in the past (last week, last month, yesterday) or that it is finished (We ate fish for lunch.)

Answer (score 1):

First, I’d remove the first “have”and the comma. “Last Friday we announced...” is fine.

Secondly, I don’t feel “announced 18 trainees” is correct, as it sounds like you are only “announcing” “the trainees”.

There are two ways to go about about resolving this, and it would depend on exactly what the message/announcement was.

1. To use “announced”:

> Last Friday we announced **that** 18 trainees were/have been selected to join our program.

2. To address only the trainees:

> Last Friday we **introduced/named** 18 trainees **who** were/have been selected to join our program.

Answer (score 0):

**Many tenses can be used correctly in this situation. Both your examples are acceptable.**

Let's summarize the situation.

1. Sometime before last Friday 18 trainees were selected to join the program
2. Last Friday that fact was announced.

Let's look at what tenses can correctly be used here. Some of them have very slightly different meanings, but the all amount to the same thing.

1. "18 trainees **were** selected." This is correct. It is simple past (the "were" is because it is passive voice). The trainees were selected in the past, and selected before last Friday. It is currently true that they *were* selected and it was true last Friday that they *were* selected.
2. "18 trainees who **have been** selected to join our program". This is also correct. Present perfect tense, passive voice. The selection took place in the past at a definite time in the past.

Also correct, although not frequently used:

1. Present tense: "Last Friday, we announced 18 trainees who are selected to join our program.". The trainees are currently in the state of being selected, so the present tense is appropriate.
2. Past perfect tense: "Last Friday, we announced 18 trainees who had been selected to join our program.". The selection of the trainees took place in the past at the time of the announcement, so past perfect is appropriate.

Note that the last two mean slightly different things: 1) "We announced the names of trainees, and those trainees are currently selected." You might use it to emphasize that the trainees are still selected at this time. 2) "We announced that the selection of trainees had taken place." You might used it as a statement of what had happened in the past, contrasting it with the condition now. There are circumstances under which they would not apply, for example you would not use 1 if some of the trainees have since been de-selected.

As FumbleFingers says. "We announced ..." is preferred over "We have announced ...".

Comment: Not trying to score points. Never mind.